# Cannot link view scene to created CustomClass

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I created a new view control on my main.storyboard. Now I would like to link that view to a customclass I created (SceneViewController in my example).  But when I try to use the dropdown box in the upperright corner my CustomClass SceneViewController does not show up....
Does anybody have a clue on what I might be doing wrong?

See image below for better insight:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/113328996@N07/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite common XCode issue. You can either type it manually not bothering that this class is not available on the list or you can close and open project again and it should appear on the list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start typing `SceneViewController` to get it to show up. If it doesn't, type the whole name, then build and clean.